# Source compiles in GCC but not Visual Studio

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

This compiles on GCC 4.6 but doesn't with VS2010 sp1:
Is it my fault or VS screwed up again?

```
 #include "stdafx.h"

enum Attribute{red_att,black_att,key_att,value_att};

struct Color{};



template<enum Attribute>
struct Tag_Value;

template<>
struct Tag_Value<red_att>
{
    typedef Color type;
};

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

Errors:
`error C2599: 'Attribute' : forward declaration of enum type is not allowed`

`error C2440: 'specialization' : cannot convert from 'Attribute' to 'Attribute'`

Comment: Where does it fail? Not all of us have a VS2010 at hand

Comment: @complainers ;) sorry, I'll paste the err code now

Comment: It refers to this line: `struct Tag_Value<red_att>`. (Using VS2008.)

Comment: is this a non-type template argument? `template<enum Attribute E>
struct Tag_Value;` ?

Comment: Have you tried just `template<Attribute> struct Tag_Value;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain what the exact problem is—my guess is that it is treating `enum Attribute` as the beginning of a new enum declaration... perhaps as a member of Tag_Value.  So you have two `Attribute` enums and it won't let you specialize one with the other.

To fix, just get rid of the `enum`:

```
template<enum Attribute> struct Tag_Value;
```

to this:

```
template<Attribute> struct Tag_Value;
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a valid and non-conflicting `stdafx.h`, that looks like valid code.

You will find people tell you that in C++, you don't have to say `enum Name` or `struct Name` if nothing is hiding `Name` (like a function called `Name`). In C you have to, because C has a different concept for looking up names. But in C++, to refer to a struct, class, union or enum, you can just use `Name`. So you can use `Attribute` instead of `enum Attribute`. But the different choice of naming the type should not make the compiler reject your code.

Comment: any idea why if I type @Johann this (@Johann) will not get print in comment box?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change this line:

```
template<enum Attribute> struct Tag_Value;
```

To this:

```
template<Attribute> struct Tag_Value;
```

Assuming you'll want to accept a template argument of type `Attribute` (an enum is a type, yes).

Comment: @unkulunkulu: Explain please?

Comment: now this, understandably, doesn't compile with gcc. `error:   expected a type, got ‘red_att’`

Comment: @nightcracker `template<typename whatever>` defines a template with first template argument to be a type, then specialization tries to specialize it for non-type constant of some `enum` type. It's incorrect.